# Mongolian Cyrillic for iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, internationalization

How can I type Mongolian Cyrillic on an iPhone?

I'm currently on version 7.1.2, and if possible, I'd like to use an Apple-produced solution (eg downloading keyboard info from Apple if that's possible) rather than a third-party app.

Additionally, I'd be curious to know how Apple decides what languages and scripts are made available. As Mongolian Cyrillic is written left to right and has a small alphabet, I would have thought it'd be easy to implement even if the audience is fairly small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Apple solutions for adding keyboards or fonts, only third party. Search the app store for Mongolian and try the Keyman app.  Unfortunately you have to upgrade to iOS 8 to have a keyboard that operates for the entire OS and not just via copy/paste.

Nobody here can tell you why Apple hasn't included some feature you want, but you can ask for it via

http://www.apple.com/feedback